# search filter in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I would like to find the count of characters matching,using the search filter in IE 11 , I am able to get the same when using ctrl+f in normal tabbed windows but when I use a new window ( separate window) the crtl+f opens another dialog box which does not show the count ,I want to know is there any possibility of finding the count with new window.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you mentioned works fine for me and I don't see a dialog box. I've opened up a new window and I still see the Ctrl+F bar counting the matching characters I type. I'm also using IE 11 but if you think that this could be a bug you can file it over the IE Connect site.

https://connect.microsoft.com/ie/feedback

Comment: you try to open a new pop up window and press ctrl+f ,then a dialog box appears,I don't see any count there.This ain't a bug but I want to know whether its possible or not.